# AWS: SNS sending SMS message to multiple phone numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, sms-gateway

From my mobile app, I'd like to send the following message to multiple phone numbers:

"John Doe invited you to a meeting.  Download meeting material http://alink.com"

This message will be `Transactional`

I have a Node.js running on an EC2.  I am a mobile app developer and new to AWS.

In my SNS console I created a Topic.  This created an ARN: `arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxx1234xxxx:MyAppName`

I have the following code in NodeJS:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var auth = require('../snsAuth');

AWS.config.update = auth

var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var params = {
    Message: "John Doe invited you to a meeting. Download meeting material http://alink.com",
    MessageStructure: 'string',
    PhoneNumber: '1xxx1234',
    Subject: 'MyApp'
};

sns.setSMSAttributes(
    {
        attributes: {
            DefaultSMSType: "Transactional"
        }
    },
    function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
);

sns.publish(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

I don't know how to send multiple phone numbers as parameters.  Based on the docs, it appears that I need to subscribe to a Topic first and then publish the topic.  If those are the right steps, how do I do that in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [subscribe API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) to subscribe a phone number to a topic by sms. But the user has to confirm their subscription to the topic before they will get any published events.

```
var params = {
  Protocol: 'sms',
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:xxx1234xxxx:MyAppName',
  Endpoint: '1xxx1234'
};
sns.subscribe(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  If the User has to confirm subscription, then I guess I just need to send a message to multiple phone numbers.

Comment: Yeah. Subscribe all the phone numbers you want. Then once the are confirmed call publish once and they all get the message.

Comment: I am hoping to avoid recipients subscribing.  Is there a way to send one SMS to multiple phone numbers without subscribing? or do I have to do it in a loop with one phone number in each call?

Comment: Yes, you can do it through sns publish, without actually subscribing them https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_publish-to-phone.html

Comment: Thanks.  but this link says I can only send one message to one phone number.  Is there a way to send a message to multiple phone numbers?

Comment: I haven't seen a batch publish but can't imagine it's much overhead to put it in a loop.